# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (fro versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have MS Server 2012R2x64 and Python3.7 , i have installed needed packages, but when i try install tensorflow, i get sush error

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (fro
m versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I saw many similar topics here, but no one helped me.

This error means that there is no version(distributuon) for my OS,

Why there is no distirbution? because on my Win 8.1 x 64, python 3.7.2 tensorflow was installed very quickly. But on my server there is more RAM, so to perform analysis i need my server.

How to install tensorflow on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow with these instructions:

[Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

In particuar, you can try using this command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

but if it does not work, additional tips or other URLs can be found under the link above.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

In case people are still having this problem, it seems TensorFlow simply stopped hosting certain versions from PyPI. The pip error should now tell you what options are actually available. For example:

```
$ pip install tensorflow==1.11.0
Collecting tensorflow==1.11.0
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.11.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.11.0
```

To install `tensorflow` normally with pip from a requirements file, you have to use one of the supported versions for example the ones listed above. The closest one for the example would be `1.13.1`. However the easiest fix is to change the requirement to `tensorflow>=1.11.0`, which will install the latest ver 1 distribution, `1.14.0`.